# How to enable javascript support on text based browser like elinks on linux virtual machine.?

Tags: javascript, linux, authorization, virtual-machine, qtextbrowser

How can I enable javascript on elinks for Microsoft login to authorize a request on a virtual machine(Linux)?

Comment: Voting to close: Asking help using specific software.

Comment: Also, try googling 'elink JS'

Comment: you first need to know how to ask a question [how to ask question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thank You @SadafNiknam